# Getting "Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded" error

Tags: apex, visualforce, viewstate

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Upload a csv file on the click of "Upload File" button. ReadFile() method is invoked
2. On click of "Action" button, all the row data will be uploaded to a custom object. Processing() method is invoked (not included in the code below, but it uses "emailList" List).

Here's the code for my controller class:

```
public class FileUploaderTest {

    public transient string nameFile {get;set;}
    public transient blob contentFile {get;set;}
    public transient string[] fileLines = new string[]{};
    public List<string> emailList = new List<string>();


        public static String blobToString(blob input, String inCharset){
        //code to convert blob to string.
    }

    public Pagereference ReadFile(){
        nameFile =blobToString(contentFile,'ISO-8859-1');
        filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
                for (Integer i=0;i<filelines.size();i++)
                {
                    emailList.add(filelines[i]);
                }
        return null;
    } 
    public Pagereference processing(){
    //Uses emailList List and logic is performed based on the elements of this list.
}
```

Everything is working as expected but I'll be facing the issue when the csv file is large. This is because "emailList" is a part of view state.
I cannot make emailList transient because I'm getting null pointer exception error. I tried making it static but oddly, no data comes into the list and the list appears to be empty.

So is there is any way I can exclude emailList from viewstate? Or, is it possible to make a copy of it within the class and clear emailList in ReadFile() itself to clear the viewstate?

Answer (score 1):

`static` behaves a lot like `transient`, in that they are not stored in the view state. The difference is that `static` variables are initialized each time the class is accessed, which is why the list appeared blank. If you need to be able to show the data in `emailList`, like a preview mode, then you need to have the data *somewhere*, it can't just be inside `ReadFile` or the data would still disappear between transactions.

If you insist on using Apex Code for this purpose, you'd need to keep the data somewhere safe, like inside a postback value or in the database somewhere. Unfortunately, this will incur some additional serialization and deserialization overhead (basically, you're reprocessing the CSV each time). Basically, would look something like this:

```
transient List<String> tempEmailList;
public List<String> emailList { get { return tempEmailList; } }
public String emailStorage { 
  get { return tempEmailList == null? null: JSON.serialize(tempEmailList); }
  set { tempEmailList = value == null? null: (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(value, List<String>.class); }
}
```

Which you would then hide inside the postback:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!emailStorage}" />
```

If this looks a bit wonky... well, it is. Typically, once you get to the point where you need more than 100kb of View State, you need to start looking at alternative methods. I would probably recommend using client-side parsing/rendering using JavaScript, then actually process the database actions using a @RemoteAction method.

If you have access to it, using the Platform Cache may also be a viable alternative, but since it is volatile, your users might have to periodically re-upload the data if they take too long reviewing it.

So, as another alternative, you might decide to just store the CSV file in a processed form (e.g. JSON.serialize to a Document file), so you can maintain the state as a record in the database until the work has been completed. This design would also give you the option to allow users to resume an incomplete attempt.